# How to solve outofmemory exception error for a dataset in C#?

Tags: c#, exception, lucene, dataset, out-of-memory

I have millions of records in my database table which I am trying to store in a Data Set (I use Data set to create Lucene index.)

The problem is Data Set is not able to handle millions of records and it is giving me out of memory exception.

```
public DataSet GetDataSet(string sqlQuery)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("Server=M-E-DB2;Database=IS;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
        sqlCmd.Connection = sqlCon;
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlCmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
        SqlDataAdapter sqlAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
        sqlAdap.Fill(ds);
        sqlCon.Close();
        return ds;

    }
```

Can someone please suggest me an alternative to handle the out of memory exception keeping in mind my scenario.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you really *need* all of the data in memory in one go? Can you not read the data in batches and build up the index that way?

Comment: I have no idea. As far as I know the index writer deletes all the data and then writes the index. I don't see any way through which I can update it. Not a Lucene expert though.

Answer (score 5):

You can get line by line with **SqlDataReader**

```
using (connection)
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        sqlCmd.Connection = sqlCon;
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlCmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                 /// you can get values
            }
        }        
        reader.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Storing is my problem not reading. SQLDataAdapter is already reading the records successfully. However, while storing them into a Dataset is causing problems.

Comment: @John - The _line by line_ is your solution. Unless you just store them anyway, that's your problem.

Comment: If your data really big i think you need work with it at file or at database. Maybe you can create temp table and work with data at it, then sync. But, sorry, i don`t now context for can help.

Comment: How will I fill the Dataset with reader? It doesnt have Fill method.

Comment: Reader help you get data in portions. If you get all data you have again error with out of memory.

Comment: @John: We're suggesting that you don't fill a DataSet to start with. Fill the index item by item, instead of passing in a DataSet.